# Content slider to show latest announcements, SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am looking for how to create a rotating slider that will display my latest announcements with title, excerpt and an image.

Looking at this project: [Content rotator for SharePoint lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18091/content-rotator-for-sharepoint-lists) it seems this is for SP2010 only?

I have many jquery sliders available, but need to know how to insert the content/search query into my slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any webpart has been developed so far that will provide what you exactly want, however as you said you need advise for where to start then I would recommend you this.

Download [SourceCode](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=1a6b87ec4988b481&id=1A6B87EC4988B481!129&authkey=!AMa7sGznNYXSbx8) for this WebPart named as [SharePoint 2013 Carousel WebPart with Nivo Slider](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/SharePoint-2013-Carousel-WebPart-with-Nivo-Slider.aspx) and in class

```
public class Nivo : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
```

and method

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Gets the slider items.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private List<SliderItem> GetSliderItems()
        {
```

Instead of getting information like image, title from Image library, you can get data from Announcements list instead.

If I had SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2012, I would had code it and test it but un-fortunately at this time I can't.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your input. I am a web developer learning sharepoint and asp for the first time. There seems to be very little information about 2013 so far, compared to 2010.

Comment: @binga30 Reason for that is, platform just came out and developers are too busy developing on SharePoint 2010 and not getting enough time to develop on SP 2013, another reason is you need high specifications machine, anyway if I answered your question you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an announcements App in the App Store that might be what your looking for.....
[Corporate News App](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/corporate-news-app-WA103532495.aspx?redir=0)

Comment: Wow that's great, thanks for the heads up will definitely test it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Codeplex slider for SP2010 that you can tailor for SP2013: http://www.ashokraja.me/post/SharePoint-2010-Announcement-Slider-Web-Part-with-bxSlider.aspx